# What does the Standard say about the namespace of lambda types?

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say that I have a setup like this:

```
namespace hi {
    template<typename L, typename R> L operator+(L l, R r) {
        // some body
    }
    auto f() {
        return [] {}; // Legal C++14
    }
}
int main() {
    auto x = hi::f();
    1 + x; // Is this legal?
}
```

The question is whether ADL on the lambda type will find the overloaded operator in that namespace by Standard.

Comment: Names belong to namespaces, types don't.

Comment: @n.m.: Types *have* names. And the name of types and the namespace of those type names influence ADL.

Comment: How about `template <typename T> void f(T t) { t + 1; } namespace N { template <typename T> void operator+(T, int) { } void g() { f([](){}); } }` for a C++11 example? It's accepted by GCC, but rejected by clang.

Comment: @NicolBolas: No, a lambda type has no name. However I was wrong, all types, even unnamed ones, have a (possibly empty) set of associated namespaces for the purpose of ADL.

Comment: Entities can be members of namespaces. Such as classes, and functions. So they belong to namespaces too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++11 says (5.1.2, p3) that the type of a lambda will be declared "`in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression.`" So in this case, the type will be declared in `f`. C++14's CD has the same language.

So the question really is what the namespace for a local class is. I don't think it has one.

C++11, section 9.8, p1, states: `The name of a local class is local to its enclosing scope.` As such, I don't believe that it has any associated namespaces (per 3.4.2, p2), and is therefore not subject to ADL.

Comment: I think 3.4.2p2 answers this independently of 9.8: "If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and its direct and indirect base classes. Its associated namespaces are the namespaces of which its associated classes are members. [...]" The only associated class is the closure type itself, and that is not a member of any namespace, so there are no associated namespaces.

Comment: @hvd: 9.8 is needed because it defines what the scope of the class's name is. For example, 9.8 *could* have defined local classes such that they were considered members (somehow) of the namespaces of the functions that they were local to. The section from 9.8 proves that local classes aren't members of a namespace.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, the scope of a name is irrelevant to ADL. The name of a nested class is local to its enclosing class, in exact analogy to local classes. Yet it can be associated with a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

§3.4.2/2 says

> If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and its direct and indirect base classes. Its associated namespaces are the namespaces of which its associated classes are members.

Namespace association only penetrates through one level of class nesting, and not through function scopes, if this is taken literally. But both Clang and GCC allow multiple levels of class nesting, and GCC makes functions scopes transparent as well.

It looks to me like multiple levels of class nesting are a defect, and local classes are an oversight in C++11, since before C++11 there was no way to take a local class out of its namespace — they weren't allowed as template arguments.